# How we can close webresource.axd and scriptresource.axd vulnerability in asp.net.?

Tags: security, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

We have tried below code in web.config

```
 <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 1):

in your web.config, at the bottom just before the closing configuration tag put the following:

```
<location path="WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="ScriptResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This did not work for me for ScriptResource.axd.  It still served the file with this in another session.

Comment: So, this will close WebResource.axd for all users? what is the sence?